# Malformed UTF-8 data Error: Malformed UTF-8 data on decrypting data in CryptoJS

Tags: php, typescript, encryption

I tried to decrypt my api response object which was encrypted in php. Encryption is working and decrypting in PHP worked perfectly too. But decrypting it in ionic 5 always return "Malformed UTF-8 data error".

**When decrypted back in PHP:**

```
Array
(
    [name] => fagbemi Ayodele
    [username] => fagbemiayodele48
    [email] => fagbemiayodele48@yahoo.com
    [createTime] => 2022-08-05 03:28:41
    [updateTime] => 
    [gender] => male
    [telephone] => 07069605705
    [constellation] => 0
    [userId] => 130
    [loginTime] => 1672319617
    [avatar] => http://localhost:83/forum_new/assets/logo/avatar.png
)
```

**PHP encryption code:**

```
function encrypt($value, string $passphrase)
    {
        $salt = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(8);
        $salted = '';
        $dx = '';
        $data = [];
        while (strlen($salted) < 48) {
            $dx = md5($dx . $passphrase . $salt, true);
            $salted .= $dx;
        }
        $key = substr($salted, 0, 32);
        $iv = substr($salted, 32, 16);
        $encrypted_data = openssl_encrypt(json_encode($value), 'aes-256-cbc', $key, true, $iv);
        $data["ct"] = base64_encode($encrypted_data);
        $data["iv"] = bin2hex($iv);
        $data["s"] = bin2hex($salt);

        return json_encode($data);
    }
```

**Ionic 5 (Typescript) decryption code**

```
async base64Decrypt(jsonStr: string, passphrase: string): Promise<any> {
    const json = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
    const salt = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(json["s"]);
    const iv = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(json["iv"]);
    const ct = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(json["ct"]);
    const concatedPassphrase = passphrase + salt;
    const md5 = [];
    md5[0] = CryptoJS.MD5(concatedPassphrase);
    let result = md5[0];
    for (let i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
        md5[i] = CryptoJS.MD5(CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(md5[i - 1]).concat(concatedPassphrase));
        result = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(result).concat(md5[i]);
    }
    const key = result.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex).substring(0, 32);
    const data = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt({ciphertext: ct}, CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(key), {iv: iv});
    return JSON.parse(data.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
  
}
```

**decryption key**

```
"key":"8cd826ce5315e72a"
```

**Encrypted data:**

```
{"ct":"2A5q0EUDjgp4JLO341jEtJz7hoJzCm6vr9AKmz3TygAmiEXz8+phACCjUwBAadf4KRUCI\/CFLrd7zjr3gp8ttsBZv3yQwYjCKVyYnMc4hhugJkstNi80ySnMCGMzKoampUBs2gtxgbEtI0a6UPJMAC3Lq8LcdQxKNdwItfbv4JbBa1+N\/akIos8\/4IgHT+47AImd6VuXouSf\/K3NUxzUDzEmBmENozi21yELHZbjkC4EcsNKoYp8mDRQA6hqRVaVqM+TtkSZNdw5MtOz5mvp\/FJ76SRXC8gXP1jL6y93s+z7e1Vlje79pTRhSCcLFDdczib+H2t2fnDZOXwaQmjZQXUV2FoloLkfWzvCF\/Rh\/AX3wtGLpp43qAH8ec6vrFOgFD1TqQqWFloOmelmp6aDMhULTG33fHmHPMNbkHWRA+k=","iv":"d6ac6a0fb929e15909942e2aceae8762","s":"22a3d46564b07b91"}
```

How can I resolve the error?

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Malformed UTF-8 data Error:
> Malformed UTF-8 data
> at Object.stringify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PHP code implements the logic of `EVP_BytesToKey()` for key derivation, which is also the *internal* key derivation function of CryptoJS.
Therefore, decryption can be significantly simplified on the JavaScript side. To do this, the passphrase must be passed as string and salt and ciphertext encapsulated in a `CipherParams` object:

```js
var passphrase = "8cd826ce5315e72a";
var jsonStr = `{"ct":"2A5q0EUDjgp4JLO341jEtJz7hoJzCm6vr9AKmz3TygAmiEXz8+phACCjUwBAadf4KRUCI\/CFLrd7zjr3gp8ttsBZv3yQwYjCKVyYnMc4hhugJkstNi80ySnMCGMzKoampUBs2gtxgbEtI0a6UPJMAC3Lq8LcdQxKNdwItfbv4JbBa1+N\/akIos8\/4IgHT+47AImd6VuXouSf\/K3NUxzUDzEmBmENozi21yELHZbjkC4EcsNKoYp8mDRQA6hqRVaVqM+TtkSZNdw5MtOz5mvp\/FJ76SRXC8gXP1jL6y93s+z7e1Vlje79pTRhSCcLFDdczib+H2t2fnDZOXwaQmjZQXUV2FoloLkfWzvCF\/Rh\/AX3wtGLpp43qAH8ec6vrFOgFD1TqQqWFloOmelmp6aDMhULTG33fHmHPMNbkHWRA+k=","iv":"d6ac6a0fb929e15909942e2aceae8762","s":"22a3d46564b07b91"}`;
var json = JSON.parse(jsonStr);

var cipherParams = {ciphertext: CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(json.ct), salt: CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(json.s)}; // apply a CipherParams object
var decryptedData = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(cipherParams, passphrase).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);            // decrypt and UTF-8 decode
var decryptedDataJSON = JSON.parse(decryptedData);                                                         // convert to JavaScript object                                                                             
console.log(decryptedDataJSON);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.1.1/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
```

A few notes:

- CryptoJS derives the IV internally, along with the key, so it does not need to be explicitly passed to the decrypting side.
- Instead of a `CipherParams` object, salt and ciphertext can alternatively be passed in the Base64 encoded OpenSSL format to `CryptoJS.AES.decrypt()`. The OpenSSL format corresponds to the ASCII encoding of `Salted__`, followed by the 8 bytes salt and the ciphertext. In this case, it would be efficient to format the data accordingly already on the PHP side:

  ```js
  ...
  return base64_encode("Salted__" . $salt . $encrypted_data);
  ```
- In `openssl_encrypt()`, `OPENSSL_RAW_DATA` should be passed as 4th parameter instead of `true` (although both are numerically identical, the latter is more transparent).
- `EVP_BytesToKey()` is considered insecure nowadays. Instead (at least) the more reliable PBKDF2 should be applied, which is supported by both PHP and CryptoJS.